# Expectation of number of lottery draws given maximum sum

Tags: probability

Given a finite set of positive numbers $N$ and a positive number $s$, how can I find the expectation of the number of times $N$ can be sampled without replacement such that the sum of samples is less than $s$?

So, if a set of random samples without replacement from a set of numbers $N$ with a maximum sum $s$ is modeled by a function $f(N,s)$, then the number of samples is a random variable $X_{N,s}=|f(N,s)|$ with possible outcomes $(0..|N|)$.

As an example, given $N=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $x=7$, then using a trivial python script to compute all permutations gives me a probability density of

$P[X=0]=0/120$, $P[X=1]=24/120$, $P[X=2]=72/120$,

$P[X=3]=24/120$, $P[X=4]=0/120$, $P[X=5]=0/120$

and an expectation $E[X]=2$, the number I am interested in.  The same function with $N=\{1,2,3,9,10\}$ gives an expected value of $1$.

It is possible that $x$ is greater than the sum of all numbers in $N$, but limiting the expected value is a trivial step afterward if it makes the math simpler.  Also, I can compute this iteratively if it doesn’t work out to a simple equation.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: If this turns out to be unsolvable without computing all permutations of $N$, a heuristic approach would be welcome.

Comment: You cannot answer this question without statistical knowledge about $N$.

Comment: I have full access to the set, I can compute whatever I need.  Sorry, I should have clarified that it is a particular set of numbers, not any set $N$.

Comment: Rakurai:  Here are two sets:  $N_1 = \{ 0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1 \}$, and $N_2 = \{ 10^5, \pi, \sqrt{17}, 42, e \}$.  Do you think your answer depends upon which of these sets is considered?

Comment: Yes, if $x=1$ then $E[f(x,N_1)]=5$ and $E[f(x,N_2)]=0$.  I just need to compute an expectation on the fly given a set $N$ and a maximum sum $x$.  If I were to compare this to a blackjack problem, then $N$ might be the starting state of the deck.

Comment: So what is $f(\cdot, \cdot )$?  You should really specify far far more than you do in your problem if you expect useful help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added an example that I hope makes sense.